# How to send GET request using Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send GET request in my Android App wrote the following code but its giving some sort of SSL error as I inspected using debugger.
Given is my code used to login via HTTP GET

```
private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
    HttpsURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }
        try {
            conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Origin","https://myserver.com");
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (response_code == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                return(result.toString());

            }else{

                return("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pdLoading.dismiss();

        if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,SuccessActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            LoginActivity.this.finish();

        }else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {

            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "OOPs! Something went wrong. Connection Problem.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

}
```

My App ends up once this function is called.

```
 org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance
```

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what sort of error.

Comment: @stdunbar No error logged just kills my app process.

Comment: Add some `Log.d(TAG, "your message..");` to suspected code so you can found where the code still works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you cast to `HttpsURLConnection`, the normal `HttpURLConnection` should do, too and works with HTTP and HTTPS.
Next I would replace `e.printStackTrace();` with `Log.e(TAG, "error creating HTTP connection", e);`, then you see what happens.
Can you post the Stacktrace here? Then we can see what error it is.

BTW:

            `conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);`

Is not necessary for simple GET requests.

Comment: That was pasted by mistake let me edit I'm not casting it

Comment: there is no stacktrace in log

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

Comment: As I suspected the cast is the problem. Change the type and cast to `HttpURLConnection` and try again.

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: By "still the same error" you mean this one: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`?

Comment: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: That was permission error. fixed it, thank you so much.